# jQuery scroll is not animating

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, jquery-animate

I am trying to get my page to scroll to a specific `<section>` on click of an href. I've been able to make the page jump to the `<section>` I want it to but it's not smooth (it's like my .animate is not working in the jQuery).

**HTML**

```
<li><a href="#about" class="about-link">about us</a></li>

<section class="about" id="about">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>about us</h1>
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $(".about-link").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can animate with elements `id` like below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <button class="click">Click Me</button>
 <div id="mydiv" style="border:2px solid black;width:800px;height:900px; background-color:orange; position:absolute;top:1000px;margin:20px;">
  hello anuradh
 </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".click").on('click',function(){
   //window.location = "#mydiv";

    $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: $("#mydiv").offset().top
        }, 2000);
   });
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I used your jQuery and it moves me to the `<section>` with the id but it still isn't and animated movement, just an instant jump. Also, I'm trying to do it with an href instead of a button.

Comment: so this scrolls smoothly, so why your one. did you give the `position` with `top` value correctly.

Comment: I believe it does have the correct top value because it jumps to where its supposed to when I click the link, but it still isn't doing it smoothly

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $(".about-link").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;
      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function() {

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

There is nothing wrong with your code. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mpzyratg/3/) I constructed demonstrating it. As you can see, it operates perfectly.

Here are some things to consider:

1. Make sure you actually have jquery in your workspace.
2. Make sure you have room to scroll (I'm assuming you do and you just posted a snippet)

I hope you manage to get it working!